# HTML that scrolls on its own

Tags: html, scroll, html-table

I want to show a HTML table on an info screen. The problem is that the table has too many entries to be shown completely on the info screen. Is there a way to make the table scroll down and back up again on its own? (Or to scroll down in an endless loop?)

Comment: Not with pure html. Javascript will be needed.

Comment: Initially you can limit the table height to the screen height and may be you can add are load more link,  like in facebook etc

Comment: I know that I will need JS. I cannot limit the table height, because it would become too small. And I cannot add a "load more" link because it is an info screen, so no user interaction will be possible.